# achartengine toScreenPoint(double) always returns nullPointerException

Tags: android, achartengine

Every time I call this method it return nullpointerexception:

java.lang.NullPointerException  at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.toScreenPoint(XYChart.java:867)

I see mScreenR of chart is null

Without using this method  toScreenPoint(double)  the charts works well this is the code:

```
    package com.insights.insights.gui;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.achartengine.chart.LineChart;
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.chart.XYChart;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.model.XYSeries;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

import com.insights.insights.R;
import com.insights.insights.local.ApplicationsController;
import com.insights.insights.model.AppMetrics;
import com.insights.insights.model.Application;
import com.insights.insights.model.Applications;
import com.insights.insights.model.Day;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ChartFragment extends Fragment {

    private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer;
    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset;
    private GraphicalView graphicalView;
    private XYSeries firstSeries;
    private XYChart chart=null;

    private String apiKey;
    private ArrayList<Day> days;

    private View view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        apiKey = getArguments().getString(getString(R.string.tabs_activity_api_key));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chart_fragment, container, false);

        v.findViewById(R.idChartFragment.container).requestFocus();

        this.view = v;

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        //      Obtaining data to plot
        Applications applications = ApplicationsController.getInstance(getActivity()).getApplications();
        ArrayList<Application> applicationArray = applications.getApplication();

        if (applicationArray != null && !applicationArray.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < applicationArray.size(); i++) {
                if (applicationArray.get(i).getApiKey().equals(apiKey)) {
                    ArrayList<AppMetrics> appMetrics = applicationArray.get(i).getAppMetrics();
                    for (int j = 0; j < appMetrics.size(); j++) {
                        if (appMetrics.get(j).getMetric().equals("Sessions")) {
                            days = appMetrics.get(j).getDay();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // If there isn't any item to plot and show a toast
        if (days == null) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.chart_fragment_no_items, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            return;
        }

        // Ploting the items
        dataset = getDataset(days);
        renderer = getRenderer();
        setRendererStyling(renderer);

        // add plot to the layout
        if (graphicalView == null) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.idChartFragment.Chart);
            chart= new LineChart(dataset, renderer);
            graphicalView = new GraphicalView(getActivity(), chart);
            renderer.setSelectableBuffer(11);

            layout.addView(graphicalView);
        } else{
            graphicalView.repaint();
        }


        if(chart!=null&&firstSeries!=null){
            for(int i=0;i<firstSeries.getItemCount();i++){
                double x = firstSeries.getX(i);
                double y = firstSeries.getY(i);

                double[] screenPoint = chart.toScreenPoint(new double[] { x, y },0);

                Log.i("puntos", x + "," + y + " = "+" ("+screenPoint[0]+", "+screenPoint[1]+")");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method for set the style of the plotter window and the string at the x
     * axis
     * 
     * @param mRenderer
     *            render to put style in
     * 
     * @param dataSetX
     *            string to set at x axis
     */
    private void setRendererStyling(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer) {
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(false);
        mRenderer.setMarginsColor(R.drawable.transperent_color);
        mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 });
        mRenderer.setShowAxes(false);
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
        mRenderer.setExternalZoomEnabled(false);
        mRenderer.setPointSize(20);
        mRenderer.setClickEnabled(false);
        mRenderer.setDisplayValues(false);
        mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        mRenderer.setYLabels(0);
        mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false);
        mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
        mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);

    }

    /**
     * Method to introduce the values of the y axis
     * 
     * @param dataSetY
     *            data to set at axis y
     * @return the data to set
     */
    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDataset(ArrayList<Day> days) {

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        firstSeries = new XYSeries("");

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

            int value = Integer.parseInt(days.get(days.size() - (13 - i)).getValue());
            firstSeries.add(i, value);

        }
        dataset.addSeries(firstSeries);
        return dataset;
    }

    /**
     * Method for set the style of the line you want to plot and create a new
     * renderer
     * 
     * @return the renderer
     */
    private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getRenderer() {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_number_label_background));
        r.setLineWidth(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.chart_fragment_line_width));
        // r.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        r.setPointStyle(PointStyle.POINT);
        r.setFillPoints(true);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        return renderer;
    }
}
```

And this is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+idChartFragment/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+idChartFragment/Chart"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>


    <AbsoluteLayout 
        android:id="@+idChartFragment/absolute"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Second Edit:**

I want to do something like this:

[image]

With my code I do this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
 package com.insights.insights.gui;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.achartengine.chart.ClickableArea;
import org.achartengine.chart.LineChart;
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.chart.XYChart;
import org.achartengine.model.SeriesSelection;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.model.XYSeries;
import org.achartengine.renderer.SimpleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.OnFocusChangeListener;
import com.insights.insights.R;
import com.insights.insights.local.ApplicationsController;
import com.insights.insights.model.AppMetrics;
import com.insights.insights.model.Application;
import com.insights.insights.model.Applications;
import com.insights.insights.model.Day;

/**
 * 
 * @author Manuel Plazas Palacio
 * 
 */
public class ChartFragment extends Fragment {

    private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer;
    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset;
    private GraphicalView graphicalView;
    private XYSeries firstSeries;
    private XYChart chart = null;

    private AbsoluteLayout absoluteLayout;
    private ImageView point;
    private LinearLayout pointInfoConatiner;
    private TextView pointNumberText;
    private TextView pointNameText;
    private TextView pointDateText;

    private Typeface avenirHeavy;
    private Typeface avenirLight;

    private String apiKey;
    private String metricName;
    private ArrayList<Day> days;

    //  The max and the min values displayed
    private double max = 0;
    private double min = 0;

    private View view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        apiKey = getArguments().getString(getString(R.string.tabs_activity_api_key));
        metricName = "Sessions";
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chart_fragment, container, false);

        v.findViewById(R.idChartFragment.container).requestFocus();

        this.view = v;

        absoluteLayout = (AbsoluteLayout) v.findViewById(R.idChartFragment.absolute);
        //      pointInfoConatiner = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.idChartFragment.pointInfoContainer);
        //      pointNumberText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.idChartFragment.pointNumberText);
        //      pointNameText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.idChartFragment.pointNameText);
        //      pointDateText =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.idChartFragment.pointDateText);
        //
        //      pointNameText.setText(metricName);

        //      Obtaining data to plot
        Applications applications = ApplicationsController.getInstance(getActivity()).getApplications();
        ArrayList<Application> applicationArray = applications.getApplication();

        if (applicationArray != null && !applicationArray.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < applicationArray.size(); i++) {
                if (applicationArray.get(i).getApiKey().equals(apiKey)) {
                    ArrayList<AppMetrics> appMetrics = applicationArray.get(i).getAppMetrics();
                    for (int j = 0; j < appMetrics.size(); j++) {
                        if (appMetrics.get(j).getMetric().equals(metricName)) {
                            days = appMetrics.get(j).getDay();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // If there isn't any item to plot and show a toast
        if (days == null) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.chart_fragment_no_items, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }

        // Ploting the items
        dataset = getDataset(days);
        renderer = getRenderer();
        setRendererStyling(renderer);

        // add plot to the layout
        if (graphicalView == null) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.idChartFragment.Chart);
            chart = new LineChart(dataset, renderer);

            graphicalView = new GraphicalView(getActivity(), chart);
            renderer.setSelectableBuffer(11);

            layout.addView(graphicalView);
        } else {
            graphicalView.repaint();
        }

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        avenirHeavy = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Avenir Heavy.ttf");
        avenirLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Avenir Light.ttf");

        graphicalView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SeriesSelection seriesSelection = graphicalView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
                double[] xy = graphicalView.toRealPoint(0);
                //creating the views
                createOnClickPointsView();

                if (seriesSelection != null) {

                    //                  debug
                    Log.d("Punto", seriesSelection.getXValue() + ", " + seriesSelection.getValue());

                    double x = firstSeries.getX(seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + 1);
                    double y = firstSeries.getY(seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + 1);
                    double[] screenPoint = chart.toScreenPoint(new double[] { x, y });

                    //                  debug
                    Log.d("Chart point", "Chart element in series index " + seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex() + " data point index "
                            + seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + " was clicked" + " closest point value X=" + seriesSelection.getXValue()
                            + ", Y=" + seriesSelection.getValue() + " clicked point value X=" + (float) xy[0] + ", Y=" + (float) xy[1]);
                    Log.d("Punto pantalla", " (" + screenPoint[0] + ", " + screenPoint[1] + ")");

                    int value = Integer.parseInt(days.get((int) (days.size() - (13 - x))).getValue());
                    String date = days.get((int) (days.size() - (13 - x))).getDate();
                    pointNumberText.setText(value + "");
                    pointDateText.setText(date);

                    //                  drawing point info
                    absoluteLayout.addView(pointInfoConatiner, new LayoutParams(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.graficapin)
                            .getIntrinsicWidth(), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.graficapin).getIntrinsicHeight(),
                            (int) (screenPoint[0] - (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.graficapin).getIntrinsicWidth() / 2)),
                            (int) (screenPoint[1] - (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.graficapin).getIntrinsicHeight()))));

                    //                  drawing point clicked
                    absoluteLayout.addView(point, new LayoutParams(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.puntoon).getIntrinsicWidth(),
                            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.puntoon).getIntrinsicHeight(), (int) (screenPoint[0] - (getResources()
                                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.puntoon).getIntrinsicWidth() / 2)), (int) (screenPoint[1] - ((getResources()
                                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.puntoon).getIntrinsicHeight()) / 4))));
                }
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Method for set the style of the plotter window and the string at the x
     * axis
     * 
     * @param mRenderer
     *            render to put style in
     * 
     * @param dataSetX
     *            string to set at x axis
     */
    private void setRendererStyling(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer) {
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(false);
        mRenderer.setMarginsColor(R.drawable.transperent_color);
        mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 });
        mRenderer.setShowAxes(false);
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
        mRenderer.setExternalZoomEnabled(false);
        mRenderer.setPointSize(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.chart_fragment_point_size));
        mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        mRenderer.setDisplayValues(false);
        mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        mRenderer.setYLabels(0);
        mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true);
        mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
        mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMax(max + 10);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMin(min - 10);
    }

    /**
     * Method to introduce the values of the y axis
     * 
     * @param dataSetY
     *            data to set at axis y
     * @return the data to set
     */
    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDataset(ArrayList<Day> days) {

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        firstSeries = new XYSeries("");

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

            int value = Integer.parseInt(days.get(days.size() - (13 - i)).getValue());
            firstSeries.add(i, value);

        }
        dataset.addSeries(firstSeries);

        XYSeries secondSeries = new XYSeries("");
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {

            int value = Integer.parseInt(days.get(days.size() - (13 - i)).getValue());

            if (i == 1) {
                max = value;
                min = value;
            }

            if (value > max)
                max = value;
            if (value < min)
                min = value;

            secondSeries.add(i, value);

        }

        dataset.addSeries(secondSeries);
        return dataset;
    }

    /**
     * Method for set the style of the line you want to plot and create a new
     * renderer
     * 
     * @return the renderer
     */
    private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getRenderer() {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

        //First chart with the line
        XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_number_label_background));
        r.setLineWidth(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.chart_fragment_line_width));
        // r.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        r.setPointStyle(PointStyle.POINT);
        r.setFillPoints(true);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);

        //      Second chart with the points
        XYSeriesRenderer r1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        r1.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple_chart_points));
        r1.setLineWidth(0);
        r1.setFillPoints(true);
        r1.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r1);

        return renderer;
    }

    public XYSeries getFirstSeries() {
        return firstSeries;
    }

    public void setFirstSeries(XYSeries firstSeries) {
        this.firstSeries = firstSeries;
    }

    public XYChart getChart() {
        return chart;
    }

    public void setChart(XYChart chart) {
        this.chart = chart;
    }

    /**
     * Method for create the views when clicking on a point of the chart
     */
    private void createOnClickPointsView() {
        //If the info is already visible 
        if (pointInfoConatiner != null)
            absoluteLayout.removeView(pointInfoConatiner);
        //              If the point is drawn
        if (point != null)
            absoluteLayout.removeView(point);

        pointInfoConatiner = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        pointInfoConatiner.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.graficapin));
        pointInfoConatiner.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        pointInfoConatiner.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 8, 0, 0);

        pointNumberText = new TextView(getActivity());
        pointNumberText.setTextSize(18);
        pointNumberText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple_chart_points));
        pointNumberText.setTypeface(avenirHeavy);
        pointNumberText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        pointNameText = new TextView(getActivity());
        pointNameText.setTextSize(18);
        pointNameText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_users_label));
        pointNameText.setTypeface(avenirLight);
        pointNameText.setText(metricName);
        pointNameText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        pointDateText = new TextView(getActivity());
        pointDateText.setTextSize(11);
        pointDateText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_users_label));
        pointDateText.setTypeface(avenirHeavy);
        pointDateText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        pointInfoConatiner.addView(pointNumberText, 0, layoutParams);
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 2, 0, 0);
        pointInfoConatiner.addView(pointNameText, 1, layoutParams);
        pointInfoConatiner.addView(pointDateText, 2, layoutParams);

        point = new ImageView(getActivity());
        point.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.puntoon));
    }
}
```

Anyone know how can I:

1-Quit the bottom border

2-Quit the line of the pink chart

3-The chart don't move when I touch the points

4- When I ask for the screen point why to many times the y value returns infinite

Comment: Thanks for this! This is a great example and answer that i've been able to implement. Only complaint is i'd like to have your drawable graficapin

Comment: i need to exactly implement like this can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be this bug in an older version of AChartEngine. I suggest you update to 1.1.0.

Also, please note that the chart must have been already displayed when calling the method. If the chart didn't display on screen then there is no way to calculate that.

Comment: I added an isChartDrawn() method in GraphicalView. You can download a version with this method here: https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.2.0/

Comment: Thanks, but I want to put buttons on the points of the chart when the chart shows but until onResume end executing I don't show the chart. You know how I can do that?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I want to draw the buttons over de cords of the points of the chart, when the user shows the chart on the screen. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You cannot draw buttons on the chart.

Comment: Can you respond to any of the new questions I just putted in the edit?

Comment: Why toRealPoint and to screenPoint if PanEnable==false always returns Infinity

Comment: I'll check that later today. In the meanwhile I suggest you accept the answer back.

Comment: There was a bug in toRealPoint() for the case when panning was not enabled. You can download a version including this fix here: https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.2.0/

Comment: It still does not working for me, I have to do more things than copy the jar file in libs folder?

Comment: You need to have at least two values in your series. Otherwise there is now way to compute these values.

Comment: One thing more, I think if you put bigger area for click on the points of the chart it works better. I say you that because I implemented an onTouchListener in a AbsoluteLayout that is over the chart doing something like that and it works better, (but when I do that to screenPoint every time returns y=-infinite )

Comment: You mean to have different values in the two datasets or have more than two values added to the dataset because I add 12 values (and I try with only a chart and still not working)

Comment: I think, the problem is that i have the chart inside a scrollView. Tahts could be the problem?

Comment: Try to do a renderer.setInScroll(true);